PCB design review of my line following robot
This is my first PCB design. It is a line following robot. I would like to give me your thoughts. What is wrong? Can I improve something?



EDITED!
First of all I would like to thank everyone for the helpful advice. I tried to implement most of them in my design. Also the professor gave me some useful suggestions. This is my final design, which I think looks a lot better thanks to all of you. Once again, thank you very much to everyone, especially @jonathanjo and @Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica for the detailed and neatly written answer. Bogdan





Decoupling of the motor driver could be cleaner if you routed the capacitors from VCC to ground directly. Also consider using SMD, will give lower inductance. Should also decouple IC2.

I would add to the mounting hole comment of @jonathanjo that you must take into account the size of the screw heads and potential washers. Here it seems that a screw head would collide with Rp3.
If you don't use plastic screws or washers, don't route traces next to the holes. When tightening the screws you may alter the solder mask and make contact with the underlaying copper traces.

@Blup1980 I added your excellent comment into my answer, attributed to you.

Missing decoupling capacitors.

To save you some work: have you tried L293D earlier? I had plenty of overheating problems with this. After about 5 minutes of work it was activating overhaeat protection. I quickly changed to L298N and performance is much better.

Your pads are all very small, leaving very thin annular rings around the holes. This would probably be ok for professional/automated soldering, but for amateur work they're likely to be easily damaged and a little more difficult to solder. The DIP packages and resistors in particular.

Funny you should mention "line following robot". Check out https://cyberneticzoo.com/early-mobile-robots/1962-emily-the-white-line-follower-bernard-dickman-american/ which I fondly remember, having actually built it, way back then, for my high school shop class project.

running a 36V op amp like LM324 at 5V is going to give reduced performance.  its totem pole output stage may not go high enough fro logic high, you may need to add pull-ups.

Thank you everyone for your comments. I edited my design based on your advice. It helped mi a lot.

Please don't be disheartened by this long list of quite small points, you've got a great starting point.
Here are some thoughts: obviously it's a small board and is apparently a university project, but you might want to apply some best practice.
This post is intended as a collection of things to think about to help you get the best out of your project.

Through-hole double-sided is perhaps unfashionable but an excellent choice for simple circuits: easy to build, easy to debug.  In my opinion it's best to learn how to make good boards like this before SMD and multilayer.
Good design requires good diagrams You might take a look at the sticky post about good circuit diagrams, in particular left-to-right flow and ground-is-down are really good practices. Your op-amp triangles aren't labelled but should be: find a way to remove the square U2 or reduce it to the power connectors.  The three op-amp subcircuits aren't labelled for function: which is left, right, straight?  Good to put the unused op-amp on the diagram as unused, check data sheet if you should ground unused inputs or outputs.
Decoupling caps Does U2 need decoupling caps?  Yes!  A typical practice is a small (usually 2.54 mm) 0.1uF adjacent on every single chip: when you place the chip footprint, you put a cap next to it.  And then check what the datasheets say, sometimes they give more instruction.

@winny says in comments: "missing decoupling"
@user1850479 says in comments: "Decoupling of the motor driver could be cleaner if you routed the capacitors from VCC to ground directly."
@Kuba has lots more suggestions on this in he other answer, make sure you read them.
There are many questions and answers on SE.EE, search for decoupling cap.


Versioning No version except date on diagram; no version or any indication of what this is on the PCB.  In general, most boards have various revisions, so it's recommended you mark boards with version and a label saying what it is.
Make it logical You've got three identical circuits but that's hard to see on the board, even though you have enough space.
Unused portions Do J10-13 do anything?
Connector numbering J12, J10, J11, J13 are in a peculiar order which is likely to be surprising at some point.
Arduino connection consider a whole Arduino Nano (or whatever you plan to use) footprint on your board.  Many other devices have "Nano-compatible footprints" which is very convenient.  It's quite possible that the Nano is cheaper than a cable.
Single pin connectors eg J1 J2 J3 can be very fiddly.  Consider grouping all the Arduino connections into a single header, which will also help with positioning.  Also if you use "single-pin" connectors, they all get marked as Pin 1, which is very error prone (see next).
Multipin connectors  Ideally, use a connector which only connects one way round, or at the very least use clear marking of pin 1 on a connector.  Always, always, always mark connector pins clearly: this is the "user interface".
Connector positioning You have connectors coming off the middle of the board (J8, J9), can't these go on the edge?  The others have somewhat haphazard placement, you might consider positioning them more carefully.  A board with connectors coming off top, bottom, left and right can be unwieldy.
Sensor rotation U1 is rotated with respect to U2 (and U3) , which will make the LED-Sensor positioning asymmetric, is this desired?
Adjustment resistors RP1, RP2 and RP3 don't match the order of the sensors or LEDs, which might be confusing.  Consider moving the LEDs adjacent to the adjustments.
Resistor size Your resistors are apparently 0.4-in. pitch, which is okay but you could certainly use smaller ones, perhaps 0.2-in.  Consider putting the LED limit resistors right next to their LEDs.  Consider putting R4, R5, R6 in some logical layout.
Power labelling It's always good to have labels for 5V, 12V, GND on the PCB for when you're debugging.  It's great to have power-on LEDs too, so you can see at a glance.  I like to have a convenient post of some kind for the oscilloscope ground crocodile clips (usually I put two holes and make a wire "croquet hoop").
Silk screen Your component IDs are very small.  All-caps is recommended.  Your LEDs need orientation marking (especially as they're not same orientation!).  Chip Pin 1 marks much bigger.

Comment by jwo: I would also suggest aligning left or right side of the label with one of sides of the component area instead of being adjacent by a corner.


Mounting holes Are they something simple like 50×70 mm?  Is the outline of the board something convenient?

(From @Blup1980) You must take into account the size of the screw heads and potential washers. Here it seems that a screw head would collide with Rp3. If you don't use plastic screws or washers, don't route traces next to the holes. When tightening the screws you may alter the solder mask and make contact with the underlaying copper traces.


Circuit comments Make sure you read the other answer from @Kuba, which has very good advice about the circuit in general.


Thank you very much for the detailed answer, i edited my design based on your advice. @jonathanjo.

My biggest gripe is that on a 2-sided layout, it's best to have one layer be ground plane with only small jumpers.
So, what I'd do is:

Remove all traces.

Move the ground plane to top layer.

Route on the bottom layer. When needing to cross two traces, make a short jumper on the top layer.

Replace sharp corners of the board with rounded corners. Your hands will thank you, especially during field service of any sort. Those corners tend to cut you up when you least have time to lose. They are not necessary with today's CNC-routed boards at all.
The sharp corners are a vestigial practice left from the time when boards were shear-cut or were on a grid-scribed panel; or when the CNC G-CODE was "written by hand". This sort of "optimization" may still matter for very high volume cost sensitive products - and only with feedback from the PCB manufacturer. If you aren't making 10,000 of it, it's a non-issue. No sharp corners.


This way, you'll have good access to the traces that carry non-ground signals, since the components won't be in the way. The ground plane continuity will also be good since instead of "slicing into" the plane with long traces, you'll be "poking small holes" in it instead.
Other comments:

Add a bulk decoupling capacitor on the board. 470μF to 1000μF. Keep the positive terminal close to the motor driver chip's positive voltage pin.

Supply for the op-amps need to be decoupled close to the chip. Keep the capacitor close to the positive supply pin of the op-amps.

Use a thick trace from power input to the bulk decoupling cap and into the motor driver.

Use thicker and short traces from the driver chip to the motor connectors.

The op-amp offset adjustment reference voltage should be stabilized. Use a TL431 to generate about 3.5-4 V, decouple it with a 10 μF capacitor, and use that to feed RP1-RP3.

You may wish to use the ground plane for the non-power electronics only, i.e. line follower LEDs and amplifiers. You'd then isolate the motor driver and the bulk cap from the ground plane, and route a direct thick trace from the driver's - pin to the bulk cap - pin to the 12 V input connector. The power ground (12 V ground) can connect to the 5 V ground at the 12 V input connector, creating a star ground. That way the motor currents will not influence the line sensor.

The pin assignments should be made on the op-amp symbols directly. The separate rectangular symbol for LM324N is not necessary.


Part of the problem is your use of the online "CAD" tool that is not very user-friendly and does not encourage good engineering practice in schematic diagrams. Oh pardon, Altium is really shipping with defaults set to "dumb" these days :(
My most important question remains: Have you tried this circuit before? If it comes from some "circuit collection" site, it's not unlikely that it won't work. The circuit looks OK at first glance, but I have no idea if the actual light levels and stability is such that it will work in practice. If this circuit was never tried in practice - ideally you should see it working and following lines! - then I would consider the first layout a prototype and add a hole pattern for a prototyping area, since it will be likely that you will have to change it.

What is the advantage of a ground plane?

Thank you very much. I used your advice for my design. It was realy helpful. @Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica
